# Sync framework Sql Log file growing

Tags: c#, sql-server, microsoft-sync-framework

My win forms application uses Sync framework 2.1 to synchronize Sql Server 2014 client and server which has over 3.5 millions of records.The initial sync completed successfully. But when secondly sync started, application keeps on running but sync does not stop. Once I checked the sql log file of both Client & Server, it has significantly increased.I shrinked the Client & Server DBs and started the Sync. Then it completed successfully. 
Does anyone knows,

1. why the log file grows When synchronizing?
2. How to avoid log file grow?
3. any other alternatives to this situation (from Sync framework)?

Answer (score 0):

Sync Fx is just like any other database client. When you write to your DB, the logs get written too. Check if your Sync Fx is configured for bulk change application. you might be sending the sync updates individually.

Comment: I found the problem. there were some primary key updates in the server. therefore application tries to update client but couldn't. I have set **e.Action = ApplyAction.RetryWithForceWrite**  in **_ApplyChangeFailed** event, and sync framework tries to apply the change. This keeps running infinitely and log file grows. thanks